# Settimeout for each user in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code that runs for each user

```
 exports.placeStake = async(req, res) =>{
   
const { amount, playTime, gameStaked, stake, Id} = req.body
      await Stake.create({ 
      
      amount:amount, 
      playTime: playTime,
      stake:stake,
      Id:Id,
      ref:crypto.randomBytes(10).toString("hex"),
      status:'pending',
      userId:req.user.id,
       }).then(()=>{
           res.status(200).send('stake placed');
           
       }).then(()=>{
         setTimeout(() => {
            axios
          .get(`https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures?id=${Id}`, {
            headers: {
              'x-rapidapi-host': 'v3.football.api-sports.io',
              'x-rapidapi-key': '58xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
           
          // update the user database with response
         
     
      }).catch((error) => {
        
        console.log(error)
      });

             
           },*2 hours*);
       }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
       
       if (error) {
         res.status(400).send(error);
      }
    });
       

  }
```

After 2 hours from when the game is staked I want to make an Api call in the settimeout to check the game and update the user's account
What I am confused about is if the settimeout is evaluated for each user, if not how to make is so?

Comment: `What I am confused about is if the settimeout is evaluated for each user` have you done *any* tests to check? Should be easy to check, you just have to check

Comment: `},*2 hours*);` that's error

Comment: @LukasLiesis no it's not...just a placeholder. I know i have to do something like 2*60*60*1000

Answer (score 0):

First of all you assume there won't be any process interruptions for 2 hours. Like restart, crash, whatever. Extremely fragile setup.

Second if you want to run anything for each, you need a loop. I don't see any loops here.